# Better way to create percentage ranges in oracle 11gr2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, group-by, percentage

I have a table like

```
Value    Average    Difference%
1        2          50
5.5      13         43
3        10         30
```

And I want to turn that into something like

```
Difference Range   #
 0-30              1
41-50              2
```

To later plot that into a histogram-like graph.

After I've wrote the typical `case when difference < 10 then 'under 10%' else when ... end` I started wondering if there was a better way to do that. Found the [PERCENT_RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions109.htm), which seemed to go that way but not quite what I was looking for.

Would be better if the step of the rages were fixed, like, each 5%:

```
case
  when dif_perc_med = 0 then 'Ok' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.05 then 'até 5%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.1 then 'até 10%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.15 then 'até 15%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.2 then 'até 20%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.25 then 'até 25%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.3 then 'até 30%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.35 then 'até 35%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.4 then 'até 40%'
  when dif_perc_med < 0.45 then 'até 45%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.5 then 'até 50%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.55 then 'até 55%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.6 then 'até 60%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.65 then 'até 65%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.7 then 'até 70%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.75 then 'até 75%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.8 then 'até 80%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.85 then 'até 85%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.9 then 'até 90%' 
  when dif_perc_med < 0.95 then 'até 95%'
else 'mais de 95%'end as rng_perc_dif
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `width_bucket` is what you are looking for? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions234.htm#SQLRF06163

Comment: exactly what I needed. wanna turn that into an answer? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple arithmetics to do that:

```
SELECT TRUNC("Difference"/5) "Rank", COUNT("Difference")
FROM T
GROUP BY TRUNC("Difference"/5);
```

If you need all values (incl. "missing" ones), you could use a join on some generated table:

```
SELECT ("Rank")*5 "From", ("Rank"+1)*5 "To", NVL(V."Cnt", 0) "Cnt" 
--           from N           to N+1
FROM (
  SELECT LEVEL-1 "Rank" FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100/5
  --          ^^
  --    start from zero
) C
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TRUNC("Difference"/5) "Rank", COUNT("Difference") "Cnt"
    FROM T
    GROUP BY TRUNC("Difference"/5)
) V
USING("Rank")
ORDER BY "Rank"
```

In this example, I've hard-coded all the `5` -- for production code you should very probably turn them into parameters.

---

Starting with *10g* (I think) Oracle does support the [`WIDTH_BUCKET`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions214.htm) function that perform mostly the same job as the above arithmetics. So you could rewrite that query as this:

```
SELECT ("Rank"-1)*5 "From", ("Rank")*5 "To", COUNT(V.ROWID) "Cnt"
--           from N-1           to N
FROM (
  SELECT LEVEL "Rank" FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100/5
  --        ^^
  --    start from one
) C
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT WIDTH_BUCKET("Difference",0,100,20) "Rank"
    FROM T
) V
USING("Rank")
GROUP BY "Rank"
ORDER BY "Rank";
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7398/29 for a a live test of those various solutions

Comment: wait. what. now I feel silly. Anyway, the comment from @a_horse_with_no_name is exactly what I was looking for. thanks though.

Comment: @filippo ;) For reference, could you post a self-accepted answer depicting how you used `WIDTH_BUCKET` to solve your issue ?